# How remove underline in link in react

Tags: html, css, underline

How set text-decoration to none in react of the link child text?
In my case this text with the 'preview-title' and 'preview-slogan' class.
[image: devtool with react link text]
I tried set it in app.css

`.preview-title, .preview-slogan {
    text-decoration: none;
}`

As well i did that to `a` tag in index.css

`a {
    text-decoration: none;
}`

Also attempted textDecorationStyle
to the element
`<div className='preview-title' textDecorationStyle="none">`
But that doesnt work too

In devtool we see the style is applied through .css but at the page it still with underline

Comment: Can you try `text-decoration: none !important;` ?

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: see here support:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration

Comment: The problem was i needed to add `a { text-decoration: none;}` not to index.css but app. css. When i have put it to app.css it have been applied to the app

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found out, it must be placed `text-decoration: none` in app.css, not in index.css.

Answer (score 4):

Please try the below-given CSS code hope it will help you. You have to set !important because you are trying to override the pre-defined style of the particular element.

```
.preview-title{
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Hope it will help you in solving your issue.

Thanks.